# How to send mail to multiple recipients on SMTP form

Tags: routes, smtp, flask-mail

I have made a form and the user can input multiple email addresses and my program will then send a mail to the email addresses. My program does collect the input but the SMTP is only sending it to one email address. I want it to send it to multiple email addresses at the one time.

Here's my code:

```
def results():
    userdata = request.form
    quantity = userdata['quantity']
    name = userdata['name']
    email = userdata['email']
    print(email)
    msg = Message(subject="Hello", sender='populargifsontwitter@gmail.com', recipients=[email],
                  body="Hi!" + name + "This is a test email I sent with Gmail and Python!")
    # calling mail and the send method and passing the message
    mail.send(msg)
    return render_template('results.html', quantity=quantity, email=email, name=name)
```

Edit: I was recommended to split it.

Here's what I did:

```
email = email.split(",")
    print(email)
    for x in email:
        msg = Message(subject="Hello", sender='populargifsontwitter@gmail.com', recipients= [x], body="Hi!"+name+"This is a test email I sent with Gmail and Python!" )
    #calling mail and the send method and passing the message
        mail.send(msg)
```

Problem: Now the email only gets sent to the second recipient and not the first one. What should I do and why is it only sending it to the second recipient?

Comment: Have you tried emails in a list.? I suggest you use mailgun API.

Comment: `recipients` takes a list of one or multiple email addresses. You have to make sure to split user supplied emails before assigning them to `recipients`. Also did you tested it with one email just to make sure that it works.

Comment: I tried to split it but the email got sent to the second email address but not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on reddit said that there was an issue with the SMTP server. They suggested adding a small delay after sending it before the end of the loop and it worked!

```
for x in email:
        msg = Message(subject="Hello", sender='janedoe@gmail.com', recipients= [x], body="Hi!"+name+"This is a test email I sent with Gmail and Python!" )
    #calling mail and the send method and passing the message
        time.sleep(2)
        mail.send(msg)
    return render_template('results.html', quantity = quantity, email = email, name = name)
```